# Crystal Reports - Display string separated by \ into rows

Tags: crystal-reports

I have data in a field that looks like this:

`<Taxonomy>\Animalia\
 <Taxonomy>\Animalia\Chordata\Vertebrata\
 <Taxonomy>\Animalia\Chordata\Vertebrata\Tetrapoda\Sauropsida\Reptilia\Eureptilia\Diapsida\Sauria\Archosauromorpha\Dinosauria\Saurischia\Theropoda\Coelurosauria\Tyrannosauroidea\Tyrannosauridae\Tyrannosaurinae\`

Basically the string can be variable length but terms are always separated by a "\".
What I would like to do is have this displayed vertically like so....

```
Taxonomy

Animalia

Chordata

Vertebrata

Tetrapoda
```

I can't seem to get that going for the entire string, I have figured out how to do it for certain parts of the string...

```
split({TERMWITHPATHSVIEW.Path},"\")[-6]
+chr(10)+
split({TERMWITHPATHSVIEW.Path},"\")[-5]
+chr(10)+
split({TERMWITHPATHSVIEW.Path},"\")[-4]
+chr(10)+
split({TERMWITHPATHSVIEW.Path},"\")[-3]
+chr(10)+
split({TERMWITHPATHSVIEW.Path},"\")[-2]
```

Since the string is of variable length, this doesn't work for displaying really long strings.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `join()` in combination with `split()`:

```
join(split({TERMWITHPATHSVIEW.Path},"\"),chr(10))
```

If you really want those extra spaces in between you can just do:

```
join(split({TERMWITHPATHSVIEW.Path},"\"),chr(10)+chr(10))
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! Thank you so much!